# Load compressed data (.npz) from file using numpy.load

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io

I have an array:

```
>>> data = np.ones((1,3,128))
```

I save it to file using `savez_compressed`:

```
>>> with open('afile','w') as f:
        np.savez_compressed(f,data=data)
```

When I try to load it I don't seem to be able to access the data:

```
>>> with open('afile','r') as f:
        b=np.load(f)
>>> b.files
['data']
>>> b['data']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#196>", line 1, in <module>
    b['data']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 238, in __getitem__
    bytes = self.zip.read(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 828, in read
    return self.open(name, "r", pwd).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 853, in open
    zef_file.seek(zinfo.header_offset, 0)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

**EDIT**

Following  @Saullo Castro's answer I tried this:

```
>>> np.savez_compressed('afile.npz',data=data)
>>> b=np.load('afile.npz')
>>> b.files
['data']
>>> b['data']
```

and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#253>", line 1, in <module>
    b['data']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 241, in __getitem__
    return format.read_array(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 440, in read_array
    shape, fortran_order, dtype = read_array_header_1_0(fp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 336, in read_array_header_1_0
    d = safe_eval(header)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\utils.py", line 1156, in safe_eval
    ast = compiler.parse(source, mode="eval")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 53, in parse
    return Transformer().parseexpr(buf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 132, in parseexpr
    return self.transform(parser.expr(text))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 124, in transform
    return self.compile_node(tree)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 159, in compile_node
    return self.eval_input(node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 194, in eval_input
    return Expression(self.com_node(nodelist[0]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 578, in testlist
    return self.com_binary(Tuple, nodelist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 1082, in com_binary
    return self.lookup_node(n)(n[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 596, in test
    then = self.com_node(nodelist[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 610, in or_test
    return self.com_binary(Or, nodelist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 1082, in com_binary
    return self.lookup_node(n)(n[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 615, in and_test
    return self.com_binary(And, nodelist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 1082, in com_binary
    return self.lookup_node(n)(n[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 619, in not_test
    result = self.com_node(nodelist[-1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 626, in comparison
    node = self.com_node(nodelist[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 659, in expr
    return self.com_binary(Bitor, nodelist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 1082, in com_binary
    return self.lookup_node(n)(n[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 663, in xor_expr
    return self.com_binary(Bitxor, nodelist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 1082, in com_binary
    return self.lookup_node(n)(n[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 667, in and_expr
    return self.com_binary(Bitand, nodelist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 1082, in com_binary
    return self.lookup_node(n)(n[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 671, in shift_expr
    node = self.com_node(nodelist[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 683, in arith_expr
    node = self.com_node(nodelist[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 695, in term
    node = self.com_node(nodelist[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 715, in factor
    node = self.lookup_node(nodelist[-1])(nodelist[-1][1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 727, in power
    node = self.com_node(nodelist[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 805, in com_node
    return self._dispatch[node[0]](node[1:])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 739, in atom
    return self._atom_dispatch[nodelist[0][0]](nodelist)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 754, in atom_lbrace
    return self.com_dictorsetmaker(nodelist[1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\compiler\transformer.py", line 1214, in com_dictorsetmaker
    assert nodelist[0] == symbol.dictorsetmaker
AssertionError
```

**EDIT 2**

The above error was in IDLE. It worked using Ipython.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When using `numpy.load` you [can pass the file name](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html), and if the extension is `.npz`, it will first decompress the file:

```
np.savez_compressed('filename.npz', array1=array1, array2=array2)
b = np.load('filename.npz')
```

and do `b['array1']` and so forth to retrieve the data from each array...

Answer (score 26):

> You can also use the `f` attribute, which leaves you with a
> `np.ndarray`:

```
images_npz = np.load('images.npz')
images = images.f.arr_0
images_npz.close()
```

The name/key of the array inside the .npz-file (e.g. `arr_0`) can be found through

```
images.keys()
```

*Note*: The `f` attribute is not documented in the docstring of load. When load reads an `npz` file, it returns an instance of the `class NpzFile`. This class is available as `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile`. The docstring of the `NpzFile` class describes the `f` attribute. (As of this writing, the source code of the class can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L95.).

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file as binary:

```
with open('afile','rb') as f:
```

Comment: Try indenting all the lines following the open! Your file is getting closed once it leaves the `with` block.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo in the question - fixed it. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same problem(AssertionError) when using numpy 1.7.1/1.8.0 with python 2.7.6 both on MAC OS and Windows. But the problem was automatically fixed after I switch to linux with python 2.7.5. Then I reinstall python 2.7.5 on MACOS and Windows and all the problem was gone.
Basically the problem is with python instead of numpy as the compiler is sending alert.So mightly the version matters.

But though npy is the serializable type of numpy, I don't think the file is small enough even with savez_compressed for large matrix.

Hopefully your problem is the same with mine