# Python: How to save 2d numpy array efficiently to disk?

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

I have a huge 2d numpy array that's suppose to work as a co-occurrence matrix. I've tried to use scipy.sparse as my data structure, but `dok_matrix` indexing is incredibly slow (4x times slower).

```
# Impossible
import numpy
N = 1000000 (1 milion)
coo = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.uint32)
```

I want to persist this array.

After searching for ways to save it I tried to use `PyTables` or `hd5py`, but I couldn't find a way to save it without running out of memory.

```
with open(name, 'w') as _file:
   np.save(_file, coo)
```

For instance, using `PyTables`:

```
    import tables
    _file = tables.openFile(
                name,
                mode='w',
                title='Co-occurrence matrix')
    atom = tables.Atom.from_dtype(coo.dtype)
    _filters = tables.Filters(complib='blosc', complevel=5)
    ds = _file.createEArray(
            _file.root,
            'coo_matrix',
            atom,
            shape=(0, coo.shape[-1]),
            expectedrows=coo.shape[-1],
            filters=_filters)
    # ds[:] = coo => not an option
    for _index, _data in enumerate(coo):
        ds.append(coo[_index][np.newaxis,:])
    _file.close()
```

And using `hd5py`:

```
import h5py
h5f = h5py.File(name, 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=coo)
```

Both methods keep increasing memory usage until I have to kill the process. So, is there any way to do it incrementally? If it's not possible to do it can you recommend another way for persisting this matrix?

EDIT

I'm creating this co-occurrence matrix like this:

```
    coo = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.uint32)
    for doc_id, doc in enumerate(self.w.get_docs()):
        for w1, w2 in combinations(doc, 2):
                if w1 != w2:
                    coo[w1, w2] += 1
```

I want to save coo (2d numpy array) to retrieve it from disk later and find co-occurrence values, like: coo[w1, w2]

Comment: Just to satisfy my own curiosity: what is *posterior loading*?

Comment: Besides storing what are you trying to do with this array?  Change individual values, access them, access slices, math?

Comment: There is the [`np.savez_compressed` option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18232374/832621), which is very fast and compact to move data around...

Comment: @SaulloCastro, same problem, try in your ipython: np.savez_compressed('testing.npz', coo=x=np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.uint32))

Comment: Is `coo` dense or sparse?  I can't create, let alone store, a `10**6 x 10**6` uint32 matrix on my system (requires 4TB of memory, if my math is right).

Answer (score 1):

`np.save` is a fast, efficient way of saving a dense array.  All it does is write a small header and then the data buffer of the array.

But for a large array, that data buffer will have `N*N*4` (for your dtype) bytes - in one contiguous memory block.  That design is also good for element access - the code knows exactly where the `i,j` element is located.

Beware that `np.zeros((N,N))` does not allocate all the necessary memory at once.  Memory use may grow during use (including saving)

`np.savez` does not help with data storage.  It does a `save` for each variable, and collects the resulting files in a zip archive (which may also be compressed).

Tables and h5py can save and load chunks, but that doesn't help if you have to have to whole array in memeory at some point - for creation or use.

Since your array will be very sparse, a `scipy` sparse matrix could save on memory, since it only stores the nonzero elements.  But it has to also store that element's coordinates as well, so storage per nonzero element isn't as compact.  There are a number of formats, each with its pros and cons.

`dok` uses a Python dictionary to store data, with keys of the form `(i,j)`.  It is one of the better formats for incrementally building a sparse matrix.  I found in in other SO questions that element access with a `dok` is slower than with a plain dictionary.  It is faster to build a regular dictionary, and then `update` the `dok`.

`lil` is another good format for incremental builds.  It stores the data in 2 lists of lists.

`coo` is convenient for building a matrix, once you have a full set of `i,j,data` arrays.

`csr` and `csc` are good for computation (esp. linear algebra kinds), and for element access.  But no good for changing sparsity (adding nonzero elements).

But you can build a matrix in one format, and readily convert it to another for use, or storage.

There have been SO questions about storing sparse matrices.  The easiest is with the MATLAB compatible .mat format (`csc` for sparse).  To use `np.save` you need to save the underlying arrays (for `coo`, `csc`, `csr` formats).  Python pickle has to be used to save `dok` or `lil`.

Do a search on `[scipy] large sparse` to see other SO questions about this kind of matrix.  You aren't the first to use numpy/scipy for co-occurance calculations of documents (it's one of the 3 main uses of scipy sparse, the others being linear algebra and machine learning).