# Saving vcf to npz and then loading to Python. No error, but no output

Tags: python, numpy, scikits

I'm trying to analyze genome data from a huge (1.75GB compressed) vcf file using Python. The technician suggested I use scikit-allel and gave me this link: http://alimanfoo.github.io/2017/06/14/read-vcf.html. I wasn't able to install the module on my computer; but I successfully installed it on a cluster which I access through vpn. There, I successfully opened the file and have been able to access the data. But I can only access the cluster through a command line interface, and that isn't as friendly as the Spyder I have on my computer; so I've been trying to bring the data back. The GitHub link says I can save the data into a npz file which I can read straight into Python's numpy; so I've been trying to do that.

First, I tried `allel.vcf_to_npz('existing_name.vcf','new_name.npz',fields='calldata/GT')` on the cluster. This created a (suspiciously small) new npz file on the cluster, which I downloaded. But when I opened up Spyder on my computer and typed `genotypes=np.load('real_genotypes.npz')`, no new variable called `genotypes` appeared in the Variable Explorer. Adding the line `print(genotypes)` produces `<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x00000__________>`

Next, thinking that I should copy everything to be sure, I tried `allel.vcf_to_npz('existing_name.vcf','new_name.npz',fields='*',overwrite=True)`
This created a 2.10GB file. After a lengthy download, I tried the same thing, but got the same results: No new variable when I try to np.load the file, and `<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x000001DB0DEC7F88>` when I ask to print it.

When I tried to Google search this problem, I saw this question: [Load compressed data (.npz) from file using numpy.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231135/load-compressed-data-npz-from-file-using-numpy-load/44693995). But my case looks different. I don't get an error message; I just get nothing. So what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `f = np.load('/path/to/your/npz_file.npz'); print(list(f.keys()))`?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen ['samples', 'calldata/AB', 'calldata/AD', 'calldata/DOS', 'calldata/DP', 'calldata/GQ', 'calldata/GT', 'calldata/NALT', 'calldata/NALTT', 'calldata/PL', 'variants/AC', 'variants/AF', 'variants/ALT', 'variants/AN', 'variants/BaseQRankSum', 'variants/CHROM', 'variants/DB', 'variants/DP',

Comment: 'variants/DS', 'variants/Dels', 'variants/END', 'variants/FILTER_LowQual', 'variants/FILTER_PASS', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheINDEL99.00to99.90', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheINDEL99.90to100.00', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheINDEL99.90to100.00+', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP98.50to98.60',

Comment: 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP98.60to98.80', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP98.80to98.90', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP98.90to99.00', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP99.00to99.30', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP99.30to99.50', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP99.50to99.90', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to100.00', 'variants/FILTER_VQSRTrancheSNP99.90to100.00+', 'variants/FS',

Comment: 'variants/HET_AB', 'variants/HET_AD', 'variants/HaplotypeScore', 'variants/ID', 'variants/InbreedingCoeff', 'variants/MLEAC', 'variants/MLEAF', 'variants/MQ', 'variants/MQ0', 'variants/MQRankSum', 'variants/NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE',

Comment: 'variants/POS', 'variants/POSITIVE_TRAIN_SITE', 'variants/QD', 'variants/QUAL', 'variants/REF', 'variants/RPA', 'variants/RU', 'variants/ReadPosRankSum', 'variants/STR', 'variants/VQSLOD', 'variants/altlen', 'variants/culprit', 'variants/is_snp', 'variants/numalt', 'variants/set']

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I don't see so many when I use .keys() on the cluster: ['calldata/GT', 'samples', 'variants/ALT', 'variants'CHROM', 'variants/FILTER_PASS', 'variants/ID', 'variants/POS', 'variants/QUAL', 'variants/REF']

Comment: Don't put code output like this in comments; edit your question if needed.  But it's clear that `f` is a valid `npz` "dictionary".  You need to read the docs for `np.savez` to see how to use this object.  `npz` load does not load the variables directly into memory.

Comment: Basically, what the other Paul said. Nothing seems to be wrong (apart from your intuition what `np.load` should do). Once you have loaded the file, the individual data items can be accessed by querying `f` like you would query a dictionary, e.g. `samples = f['samples']`, etc.